# sub query issue

Tags: sql

I have the query below which is causing me issues.  It is totaling fine however as I have different service dates its grouping by distinct then servicedate, but I just want distinct districts with the totals next. How can I get round this as I'm confused now!!!

```
SELECT DISTINCT(DISTRICT), 
        Sum(completed) as TotalCompleted, 
        MONTHNAME,
        MONTH

FROM( SELECT  TBL_PROPERTY.DISTRICT,
        TBL_SERVICE.SERVICEDATE, 
        DATENAME(MONTH, SERVICEDATE) AS MONTHNAME,
        CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(YEAR, SERVICEDATE) + '00')) + DATEPART(MONTH, SERVICEDATE) AS MONTH,
        COUNT(tbl_property.Propref) AS Completed

FROM TBL_SERVICE INNER JOIN TBL_PROPERTY ON TBL_SERVICE.PROPREF = TBL_PROPERTY.PROPREF 

WHERE (TBL_PROPERTY.CONTRACT ='ma2') AND 
        (LASTSERVICEDATE BETWEEN '01/jun/2009' AND DATEADD(hh,23,'15/jun/2009')) AND 
        (NOT (TBL_SERVICE.BILLCODE1 = 'NA')) AND  
        (TBL_SERVICE.STATUS = 'Serviced') AND 
        (PROPERTYCLASS = 'cont') 

GROUP BY DISTRICT, servicedate
) As sub1

GROUP BY DISTRICT, monthname, month, Completed
```

Example data

So for example I currently see

District1 - 2 - June 
District1 - 5 - June

And I want to see

District1 - 7 - June

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data and a resultset you want to get?

Answer (score 2):

if i read you correctly, you only want to see DISTRTICT, SUM(COMPLETED).  if this is the case, you should just

```
 SELECT DISTRTICT, SUM(COMPLETED) FROM...
```

and at the end

```
 GROUP BY DISTRICT
```

**edit:**

with your updated request, i suggest you do the following:

```
 SELECT DISTRTICT, SUM(COMPLETED), MONTHNAME FROM...
```

and at the end

```
 GROUP BY DISTRICT, MONTHNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked it through thoroughly, but it looks like your problem is you have "completed" which is your aggregate in your GROUP BY at the end.

Change the last line to just as below and see if that works.

```
GROUP BY DISTRICT, monthname, month
```

Comment: I took the completed out and i get less results but im still getting for one district 2 sets of results for the same month and i just want one district, 1 month?

So example i currently see

District1 - 2 - June
District1 - 5 - June

And i want to see

District1 - 7 - June